Unable to compile iOS Framework with OpenCV - getting error "Expected identifier"
I am creating a iOS native framework for my React Native App. I am using OpenCV capabilities and other core modules to get certain results.
I am getting below error when trying to run the code:

Below is the code where the error is generated:
blenders.h
enum { NO, FEATHER, MULTI_BAND };

exposure_compensate.h
enum { NO, GAIN, GAIN_BLOCKS, CHANNELS, CHANNELS_BLOCKS };

seam_finders.h
enum { NO, VORONOI_SEAM, DP_SEAM };

Error generated is as follow:
Expected identifier

Necessary code I have added in the my framework:
PrefixHeader.pch
#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#endif /* PrefixHeader_pch */

OpenCVWrapper.h
#import <opencv2/opencv2.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

...OTHER CODE...


OpenCVWrapper.mm
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>

...OTHER CODE...

FrameworkName.h (Header File)
// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <FrameworkName/PublicHeader.h>
#import <FrameworkName/OpenCVWrapper.h>

UPDATE 2
After few comments suggested I moved my OpenCVWrapper.h import at the last and imported other header first. Below is the code
OpenCVWrapper.mm
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"

After this change the above error disappeared, and a new error got generated in header file. Below is my header file code
OpenCVWrapper.h
#import <opencv2/opencv2.h>   #throws error ('opencv2/opencv2.h' file not found)
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

Below is the screenshot for the same:

I kept all the imports of opencv above apple headers and first error got resolved by unable to file header file is new. When I tried the same thing as an individual project of Swift it was working, but when I try to build everything in the framework it is breaking.

Blockquote


Please post code, dana and error messages as text

#import "OpenCVWrapper.h" pulls in Apple headers before OpenCV headers. Try putting it last.

@n.m.couldbeanAI The image is not my code it is coming from OpenCV Library. Also the error is mentioned in question.

@RetiredNinja, when i move #import "OpenCVWrapper.h" at the last in imports in mm file, I am getting error in OpenCVWrapper.h file: 'opencv2/opencv2.h' file not found

Please read this All error messages show context such as line numbers and file names. Your question does not contain any.

When you import blender.h make sure to import it before any of Apple header file.

@n.m.couldbeanAI updated the question and pasted error in text and code as well as image :)

@QuangHoang I updated my header import and getting new error. Updated the question with Header Update 2, Still unable to run it as a ios native framework.

The correct header file is: <opencv2/opencv.hpp>, not <opencv2/opencv.h>. Also, not sure if I've seen #import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h> file before either.

in the OpenCVWrapper.mm, move #import <opencv2/opencv2.h> to the top of all imports, worked for me
